# Binding a function that is already bound to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have a bunch of elements that get three different classes: `neutral`, `markedV` and `markedX`. When a user clicks one of these elements, the classes toggle once: neutral -> markedV -> markedX -> neutral. Every click will switch the class and execute a function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".neutral").click(function markV(event) {
    alert("Good!");
    $(this).addClass("markedV").removeClass("neutral");
    $(this).unbind("click");
    $(this).click(markX(event));
  });
  $(".markedV").click(function markX(event) {
    alert("Bad!");
    $(this).addClass("markedX").removeClass("markedV");
    $(this).unbind("click");
    $(this).click(neutral(event));
  });
  $(".markedX").click(function neutral(event) {
    alert("Ok!");
    $(this).addClass("neutral").removeClass("markedX");
    $(this).unbind("click");
    $(this).click(markV(event));
  });
});
```

But obviously this doesn't work. I think I have three obstacles:

1. How to properly bind the changing element to the already defined function, sometimes before it's actually defined?
2. How to make sure to pass the event to the newly bound function [I guess it's NOT accomplished by sending 'event' to the function like in markX(event)]
3. The whole thing looks repetitive, the only thing that's changing is the alert action (Though each function will act differently, not necessarily alert). Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: What is the purpose of this line: `$(this).click(markV(event));`? It seems that the intent of code the here is to run through the states continuously after the first user-click.

Comment: Are you really want a endless loop?

Comment: @pktangyue: There is no infinite loop

Comment: @Bergi yes, I understand what he wants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to constantly bind and unbind the event handler.

You should have one handler for all these options:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var classes = ['neutral', 'markedV', 'markedX'],
        methods = {
            neutral: function (e) { alert('Good!') },
            markedV: function (e) { alert('Bad!') },
            markedX: function (e) { alert('Ok!') },
        };

    $( '.' + classes.join(',.') ).click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);

        $.each(classes, function (i, v) {
            if ( $this.hasClass(v) ) {
                methods[v].call(this, e);
                $this.removeClass(v).addClass( classes[i + 1] || classes[0] );
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m3CyX/

Answer (score 1):

For such cases you need to attach the event to a higher parent and **Delegate the event .**

**Remember that events are attached to the Elements and not to the classes.**

Try this approach

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var $target = e.target;
    if ($target.hasClass('markedV')) {
      alert("Good!");
      $target.addClass("markedV").removeClass("neutral");
    } else if ($target.hasClass('markedV')) {
      alert("Bad!");
      $target.addClass("markedX").removeClass("markedV");
    } else if ($target.hasClass('markedX')) {
      alert("Ok!");
      $target.addClass("neutral").removeClass("markedX");
    }
  });
});
```

**OR**  as @Bergi Suggested

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', 'markedV',function (e) {
    alert("Good!");
    $(this).addClass("markedV").removeClass("neutral");
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'markedX',function (e) {
    alert("Bad!");
    $(this).addClass("markedX").removeClass("markedV");
  });
  $(document).on('click', 'neutral',function (e) {
    alert("Ok!");
    $(this).addClass("neutral").removeClass("markedX");
  });
});
```

Here document can be replaced with any static parent container..

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery for the event delegation?

Answer (score 0):

> How to properly bind the changing element to the already defined function, sometimes before it's actually defined?

You don't bind elements to functions, you bind handler functions to events on elements. You can't use a function before it is defined (yet you might use a function above the location in the code where it was *declared* - called "hoisting").

> How to make sure to pass the event to the newly bound function [I guess it's NOT accomplished by sending 'event' to the function like in markX(event)]

That is what happens implicitly when the handler is called. You only need to pass the function - [do not call it](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2)! Yet your problem is that you cannot access the named function expressions from outside.

> The whole thing looks repetitive, the only thing that's changing is the alert action (Though each function will act differently, not necessarily alert). Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Yes. Use only one handler, and decide dynamically what to do in the current state. Do not steadily bind and unbind handlers. Or use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).